# Moment.js not displaying local Date and Time format

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to display a time stamp for the user if a comment was older than 24 hours. The following code does that but it is still showing my (US) date and time format for my developers in Pakistan. Instead of mm/dd/yy it should display dd/mm/yy. Any reason why it is not working correctly? Here is my code.

```
//get date of comment
          let commentDateUTC = item.createdOn;

          //convert it to local time
          let commentLocalTime = moment.utc(commentDateUTC).local().toLocaleString();

          //determine amount of time elapsed between comment and current time
          let nowObj = { 'now': moment(commentLocalTime).fromNow() }

          //determine if more than 24 hours has elapsed since the comment was created
          let currentTime = moment().local().toLocaleString();
          let elapsedTime = moment(currentTime).diff(commentLocalTime, 'hours');

          //if yes, concatenate the item.createdOn and the nowObj.now value
          if (elapsedTime >= 24) {
            nowObj.now = `${moment(commentLocalTime).format('l LT')} (${nowObj.now})`
          }
```

Comment: Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the answer. You have to grab the locale from the browser settings and then set it using `moment.locale();`. I wish the docs were a little more clear on this....

```
      if (elapsedTime >= 24) {
        var locale = window.navigator.language;
        moment.locale(locale);
        nowObj.now = `${moment(commentLocalTime).format('l LT')} (${nowObj.now})`
      }
```